# Linearity of the supremum $\text{sup}$

Tags: real-analysis

In my lecture notes, the $C^1$-norm on the space of continuously differentiable functions $C^1([a,b],X)$ with $X$ a Banach space is given by $$\lVert u\rVert_{C^{1}} = \text{max}_{t}(\lVert u(t)\rVert + \lVert u'(t)\rVert) $$

However, in other books it's given as $\lVert u\rVert_{C^{1}} = \text{max}_{t}\lVert u(t)\rVert + \text{max}_{t} \lVert u'(t)\rVert$

I always thought that if $A$ and $B$ are two sets, then $\text{sup}(A + B) = \text{sup}A + \text{sup}B$ but a tutor recently told me that this is in general not correct.

So I am confused whether those two $C^1$-norm definitions are always equivalent. When do $\text{"sup"}$ and/or $\text{"max"}$ fail to be linear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that they define *equivalent norms*. Meaning there exist constants $C_1$, $C_2$ so that 
$$
C_1(\text{max}_{t}\lVert u(t)\rVert + \text{max}_{t}\lVert u'(t)\rVert) \leq \text{max}_{t}(\lVert u(t)\rVert + \lVert u'(t)\rVert)\leq C_2 (\text{max}_{t}\lVert u(t)\rVert + \text{max}_{t}\lVert u'(t)\rVert)
$$
It's obvious that we could take $C_2=1$, by the property you cited. For $C_1$, note that 
$$
\text{max}_{t}(\lVert u(t)\rVert + \lVert u'(t)\rVert)\geq 
\text{max}_{t}(\lVert u(t)\rVert )
$$
and 
$$
\text{max}_{t}(\lVert u(t)\rVert + \lVert u'(t)\rVert)\geq 
\text{max}_{t}(\lVert u'(t)\rVert)
$$
and so adding the two inequalites, we have $C_1=\frac12$.